# IndexError file: list index out of range( arithmetic mean)

Tags: python-3.x

A file is given, there are 4 columns in it, (index, age, height (inches), weight (pounds)) the file length is 20000+ the task is the following, i need to add the weight and height, and get the average value (I also tried to convert inches and pounds to cm and kg) I added the column and divided by the number, but I get this error **mean + = float (line [2]) IndexError file: list index out of range**

```
def data_scv():
    with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        next(csv_reader)
        mean = 0
        n = 0
        for line in csv_reader:
            mean += float(line[2])
            n += 1
            ave_height = str((mean / n) * 2.54)
        for line in csv_reader:
            mean += float(line[3]) 
            n += 1
            ave_weight = str((mean / n) / 2.205)

        return f'Average Height(Centimeters) is - {ave_height} <br> Average Height(Kilograms) is - {ave_weight}'
```

Comment: Debug the value of line just before the exception.

Comment: It looks like you might have incomplete data (3 rather than 4) columns for one of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly (python isn't exactly my expertise) your issue is that you're trying to start your index in the position 1. Python's first position is position 0.